# setrlimit in Ruby

Tags: ruby, systems-programming

I am trying to limit the execution time of a ruby process using the following code:

```
trap("XCPU") do
  abort "Max Time exceeded"
end

Process.setrlimit(:CPU, 5)

loop do

end
```

The process does end but the trap code does not run (I just get 'killed' on the command line). However when I set the hard limit to a value greater than 5 the trap code runs

```
trap("XCPU") do
  abort "Max Time exceeded"
end

Process.setrlimit(:CPU, 5, 6)

loop do

end
```

Why is the first code not working?

Comment: This is strange, because in my Mac OS both the codes are running as expected. What OS are you using?

Comment: I am running the code on [link](https://c9.io), they use ubuntu on their (virtual) machines.

Answer (score 2):

The XCPU signal (`SIGXCPU`) is only sent upon a *soft* limit. When the *hard* limit is reached, a KILL signal (`SIGKILL`) is sent instead. KILL signals cause the program to terminate immediately, and cannot be caught.

Taken from [here](http://www.computerhope.com/unix/signals.htm):

> The XCPU signal is sent to a process when it has used up the CPU for a
>   duration that exceeds a certain predetermined user-settable value. The
>   arrival of an XCPU signal provides the receiving process a chance to
>   quickly save any intermediate results and to exit gracefully, before
>   it is terminated by the operating system using the SIGKILL signal.
>
> The KILL signal is sent to a process to cause it to terminate
>   immediately. In contrast to SIGTERM and SIGINT, this signal cannot be
>   caught or ignored, and the receiving process cannot perform any
>   clean-up upon receiving this signal.

By calling [`Process.setrlimit`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Process.html#method-c-setrlimit) without a second parameter, the hard limit defaults to being equal to the soft limit. As such, at least on your operating system, it seems the `SIGKILL` is being sent before a `SIGXCPU` can be handled by your `trap` block.

Here is a quick demo to show why the second approach always works:

```
t = Time.now
trap("XCPU") do
  abort "Max Time exceeded. Total running time: #{(Time.now - t).round} seconds"
end

Process.setrlimit(:CPU, 2, 5)

loop do
end

# => "Max Time exceeded. Total running time: 2 seconds"
```

The hard limit is not reached before the `trap` block executes, so the code runs as you expect.

Comment: Excellent answer, wish they would mention that in the ruby docs.